# Sending id (primary key) to 2 different databases in Node (Mongo,Psql)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend, psql

I have a homework of todo list and I want to create it with 2 different DB with the same data. how can I have the same primary key in mongo and psql. I thought to do it with UUID in the backend. there is a basic way to do it? sorry, I'm a beginner.

that's an example of my addToDo how can I have the same prim key?

```js
const addTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { content } = req.body;

  const createdPlace = new Url({
    content: content,
    enable: false,
  });
  // Sending it To Mongo
  try {
    await createdPlace.save();
    await pool.query("INSERT INTO todo (content, enable) VALUES ($1, $2)", [
      content,
      false,
    ]);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError("Creating Place fails mongo");
    return next(error);
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB and Postgres handle primary keys differently by default, but you can make them work the same.

In MongoDB primary key field is called _id, and it is most often generated by the client (but can be generated by the server) and is, by default, a hexadecimal string converted to a special type.

In Postgres primary key can be any field, the default is most commonly id and the value is generally an autoincrementing integer and is generated by the server.

To equalize the two databases:

- Create the id value on the client side. You can use the MongoDB driver to generate a new ObjectId, convert that value to string and use the string value with both databases.
- Call your primary key column `_id` in Postgres.
- Declare the Postgres column of type string.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and perfect Answer.

```js
const addTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { content} = req.body;

  const createdPlace = new Url({
    content: content,
    enable: false,
  });
  // Sending it To Mongo
  try {
    console.log(createdPlace._id);
    await createdPlace.save();
    await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO todo (todo_id ,content, enable) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)",
      [createdPlace._id, content, false]
    );
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError("Creating Place fails");
    return next(error);
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
};
```